# Connect an XLR mic to a raspberry pi

Tags: microphone

I am looking to connect an XLR microphone to my raspberry pi 4. The microphone needs a preamp, do you have any suggestions regarding what components should I buy? (both preamp and something to connect it to the actual raspberry) Take into consideration that this whole system will be included in a buoy, so I am looking at something to attach directly to the raspberry, nothing made to stay on a desk.

Comment: Raspberry Pi is irrelevant to your question ... you are asking about connecting a microphone to a Linux computer